# comparison of parsed data using linux and the use of that comparison in ' if ' or while loop

Tags: linux, parsing, if-statement, comparison, while-loop

I am having a problem with the parsing and comparison of data as follows.

```
thinningCriteria="$(cat thinningCriteria$j.k)"
minThickElement="$(cat minimumThickness$j.k)";
d= "$(cat BHF$j.k)";
echo $d
echo $minThickElement
echo $thinningCriteria
```

for d it gives errror as follows, so this is the first problem.

```
N o r m a l    t e r m i n a t i o n
./dynaOffenRigid.sh: line 137: 1000: command not found
```

where

```
d= "$(cat BHF$j.k)";   is on line 137  and the file has a value of 1000
```

secondly I have to compare two values  like below

```
if (( $minThickElement -lt $thinningCriteria ))

then

fi
```

in this case the error is as follows.

```
999979
986667
./dynaOffenRigid.sh: line 147: ((: -lt 986667 : syntax error in expression (error token is "986667 ")

the only value in BHF$j.k is 1000
the only value in thinningCriteria$j.k    is   999979
the only value in minimumThickness$j.k    is   986667
```

I dont know what am I doing wrong when I am comparing, and why there is are error for my shell.
please all tell me the usage of while loop I used

```
while [ $minThickElement -gt $thinningCriteria ]  but same error.
```

I expect some suggestions from experts. As I cant find the solution.

best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem 1:
change

```
d= "$(cat BHF$j.k)";
```

to

```
d="$(cat BHF$j.k)"
```

problem 2:

try

```
[[ $minThickElement -lt $thinningCriteria ]]
```

Comment: for d it again said command not found.   i used                                                               d= "$(cat BHF$j.k)"

echo $d

Comment: @hamaskhan, did you copy my line? you had a blank after the '='. remove it.

Comment: the problem is that I am using a loop, in which j is the counter so it has to take the value from BHF1 for first loop and BHF2 for loop 2. However I think it is confusing two $ , how should I parse it?

Comment: @hamaskhan the problem is not about the loop. your variable (d) assignment is not correct. it should be `d=foo` not `d= foo` remove the " " from your code.

Comment: you mean to remove the white space between equal sign and double quotes or only double quotes?   regards

Comment: `=_"$(...)"` the _ should be removed. you can see in my answer.